# How do I hide all columns in a treelistitem?

Tags: python, wxpython, treelist

I'm using the `HyperTreeList` to display a list of items with the name in the first column, and a "Remove" button in the second column. I wrote a function to filter what is displayed in the tree by some text in a `TextCtrl`. To hide the `TreeListItems`, I'm doing this:

```
treelist.HideItem(branch, True)
```

where treelist is a `HyperTreeList` and branch is a `TreeListItem`. The first column hides just fine, but none of the buttons in the second column hide. How do I get all columns in a `TreeListItem` to hide?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/hypertreelist.HyperTreeList.html#hypertreelist.HyperTreeList.SetColumnShown), this should work:

```
treelist.SetColumnShown(column_index, False)
```

but this will hide that column for everything. If I understand what you're saying, the row you are trying to hide doesn't actually disappear, just the value of the first column. In that case, you might have to refresh the widget with `treelist.Update()` to get the rest of the row to disappear.

Comment: `SetColumnShown` gave me some weird behavior, but updating almost gave me what I wanted. I just don't think it's possible to hide an entire row without some modification to `HyperTreeList`. What I ended up doing was flagging the items that should be shown by the filter, deleting all children of the root, and rebuilding the tree with the flagged items.

Comment: Rather than rebuild the list, you could also use `treelist.Delete(node)`. This removes the node completely (not just hiding it), so if you wanted to reshow that node, then you would then have to keep track of its position and add it back in.